# Coordinates interpolation at exact time boundaries using cut.trip() from "trip" library in R

Tags: r, datetime, interpolation, spatial

I am trying to calculate distances between 2 moving objects. These objects are recorded in 2 different temporal resolutions (3 mins and 2 hours). I understand that I need to interpolate the coarser object (2 hours) e.g. using linear interpolation at the exact time boundaries of the finer object (3 min).

I try do this by using `cut.trip()` from the `trip` library however I am getting the following error message: *Error in cut.trip(tr, bound.dates) : object 'datebounds' not found* . I even get the same error message when I run the simple example provided in the library's [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trip/trip.pdf) (page 6).

Copy of a simple example and error message below:

```
library(sp)
library(trip)

set.seed(66)

d <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=rnorm(100, 1, 10), 
     tms= as.POSIXct(as.character(Sys.time()), tz = "GMT") + c(seq(10, 1000, length=50),
     seq(100, 1500, length=50)), id=gl(2, 50))
coordinates(d) <- ~x+y

tr <- trip(d, c("tms", "id"))
bound.dates <- seq(min(tr$tms) - 1, max(tr$tms) + 1, length=5)

trip.list <- cut(tr, bound.dates)
Error in cut.trip(tr, bound.dates) : object 'datebounds' not found
```

I do not understand what is the `datebounds` object or what am I doing wrong. Could you please help me resolve this error message?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the `trip` package version 1.1-19 (and several previous versions - I'm the author).

You can fix this manually in an R session by using `fixInNamespace(cut.trip, "trip")` and editing the source of the function to put line 11 inside the `if` clause:

```
function (x, dates, ...) 
{
    tor <- getTORnames(x)
    if (is.character(dates)) {
        if (length(dates) > 1) 
            stop("if dates is character, length(dates) should be 1L")
        levs <- levels(cut(x[[tor[1]]], dates))
        datebounds <- seq(as.POSIXct(levs[1L], tz = "GMT"), by = dates, 
            length = length(levs) + 1)
        dates <- datebounds  ## line  moved into the if clause
      }
   ##   dates <- datebounds
```

I'll fix this and release an update. Thanks for the report.

The source project is here: https://github.com/mdsumner/trip

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I've edited the code as above. However, this has triggered another error message:
Error: could not find function ".single.trip.split".
Any ideas?

Comment: I've totally rewritten this function, in case you still care. You can install 1.1-20 with devtools::install_github("mdsumner/trip")  (not on CRAN yet)